# how to run such sql query. I am facing an error here ORA-01427

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a sql query

```
select a.unit_code unit,
       a.gh_vill pl_vill,
       a.gh_grow pl_grow,
      (select gh_area 
         from w_cane_survey_2013 b 
        where b.croptype_code > 12 and a.gh_no = b.gh_no ) as paudha,
      (select gh_area 
         from w_cane_survey_2013 b
        where b.croptype_code < 13 and a.gh_no = b.gh_no) as pedi 
  from w_cane_survey_2013 a 
 where a.unit_code = '03' and a.gh_vill = '9991' and gh_grow = '1';
```

when I execute it I am getting an error

**ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

*Cause:

*Action:**

Comment: Clearly one of these selects returns more than one row: (select gh_area from w_cane_survey_2013 b where b.croptype_code > 12 and a.gh_no = b.gh_no ) or (select gh_area from w_cane_survey_2013 b where b.croptype_code < 13 and a.gh_no = b.gh_no). Try to come up with conditions here which force returning exactly one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query i hope it be helpful:

```
select unit_code as unit,
   gh_vill as pl_vill,
   gh_grow as pl_grow,
   case when croptype_code > 12 then gh_area end as paudha,
   case when croptype_code < 13 then gh_area end as pedi
from 
w_cane_survey_2013 
where 
unit_code = '03' and gh_vill = '9991' and gh_grow = '1' 
Group by
unit_code, gh_vill , gh_grow, croptype_code, gh_area;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the sub-query returned more than one rows. Add one more condition of ROWNUM=1 in the sub-query and try.

```
select 
    a.unit_code unit, 
    a.gh_vill pl_vill, 
    a.gh_grow pl_grow, 
    (select gh_area from w_cane_survey_2013 b 
      where b.croptype_code > 12 and a.gh_no = b.gh_no and ROWNUM=1) as paudha, 
    (select gh_area from w_cane_survey_2013 b 
      where b.croptype_code < 13 and a.gh_no = b.gh_no and ROWNUM=1) as pedi 
from 
    w_cane_survey_2013 a 
where 
    a.unit_code = '03' and 
    a.gh_vill = '9991' and 
    gh_grow = '1';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly seen that you are fetching more than one rows .. kindly see your table or do your restriction more so that you can get one row only.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct 
a.unit_code unit, a.gh_vill pl_vill, a.gh_grow pl_grow, a.gh_srno,
nvl((select gh_area 
     from w_cane_survey_2013 b 
     where b.croptype_code > 12 and a.gh_srno = b.gh_srno ),0) as paudha,
nvl((select gh_area 
     from w_cane_survey_2013 b 
     where b.croptype_code < 13 and a.gh_srno = b.gh_srno),0) as pedi
from w_cane_survey_2013 a
where a.unit_code = '03' and a.gh_vill = '9991' and gh_grow = '1';
```

I used distinct because If I use **rownum = 1** in sub query then it return only one row even there was 16 rows for this combination
and also as @user2780501 answered I do the same thing.

Now I am getting proper record using above query.